# How to set proxy on rstudio from dockerhub behind a proxy?

Tags: r, docker, rstudio

I downloaded rocker/tidyverse from dockerhub. I tried installing a package and was greeted with:

URL 'https://cran.rstudio.com/src/contrib/PACKAGES.rds': status was 'Couldn't connect to server'

After logging into rstudio, I tried executing all the commands shown here:
https://support.rstudio.com/hc/en-us/articles/226914208-Installing-packages-on-RStudio-Connect-from-behind-a-proxy

Though I still get the same error. How can I set my proxy to be able to install packages?

Update:

I am getting the following error when attempting to run this in the rstudio:

```
library(httr)
set_config(use_proxy(url="my.proxy.url", port=XXX, username="my_user_name", password="my_password"))
set_config( config( ssl_verifypeer = 0L ) )
```

Followed by install:

```
install.packages("fpc", dependencies = TRUE)


Warning in install.packages :
  URL 'https://cran.rstudio.com/src/contrib/PACKAGES.rds': status was 'Couldn't connect to server'
Warning in install.packages :
  URL 'https://cran.rstudio.com/src/contrib/PACKAGES.gz': status was 'Couldn't connect to server'
Warning in install.packages :
  URL 'https://cran.rstudio.com/src/contrib/PACKAGES': status was 'Couldn't connect to server'
Warning in install.packages :
  unable to access index for repository https://cran.rstudio.com/src/contrib:
  cannot open URL 'https://cran.rstudio.com/src/contrib/PACKAGES'
Installing package into ‘/usr/local/lib/R/site-library’
(as ‘lib’ is unspecified)
Warning in install.packages :
  URL 'https://cran.rstudio.com/src/contrib/PACKAGES.rds': status was 'Couldn't connect to server'
Warning in install.packages :
  URL 'https://cran.rstudio.com/src/contrib/PACKAGES.gz': status was 'Couldn't connect to server'
Warning in install.packages :
  URL 'https://cran.rstudio.com/src/contrib/PACKAGES': status was 'Couldn't connect to server'
Warning in install.packages :
  unable to access index for repository https://cran.rstudio.com/src/contrib:
  cannot open URL 'https://cran.rstudio.com/src/contrib/PACKAGES'
Warning in install.packages :
  package ‘fpc’ is not available (for R version 3.4.0)
```

Comment: What is your OS ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try something like this:

```
library(httr)
set_config(use_proxy(url="my.proxy.url", port=XXX, username="my_user_name", password="my_password"))
set_config( config( ssl_verifypeer = 0L ) )
```